# How to post an array to Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

I'm creating APIs with Express.js and SQL Server. I been posting an object which is  easy and very simple, but now i have a new question: how to post an array?

Let's say i have a table which stores only two params:

```
Table_A
Id | CouponId
```

In fact, the only record that stores is `CouponId`, 'cause the `Id` is created by SQL Server on every record. So, the case is that i get a list of coupons from an api, and the idea is select from one to 'n' with a checkbox and save the selection.

This my code so far:

```
    function getList(){
      $http.get('/api/coupons')
      .then(function(data){
            $scope.infoCoupons = data.data.Response;
    }
```

On the HTML view:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-click="selectAll()"/> <a style="font-size:17px;color:black;text-decoration:none;">Select all coupons</a>
                <ul class="coupon-list">
                    <li ng-repeat="coupon in infoCoupons">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="coupon.Select" ng-click="checked"/> <a style="font-size:17px;color:black;text-decoration:none;">{{coupon.CodeCoupon}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Then, to get the selected coupons:

```
$scope.selectAll = function(){
    $scope.all = !$scope.all;
    $scope.infoCoupons.forEach(function(o){
        o.Select = $scope.all;
    });
}

function chosenCoupons(){
    var result = new Array();
    var checked = 0;

    $scope.infoCoupons.forEach(function(e){
        if(e.Select === true){
            result.push(e.Id);
            checked +=1;
        }
    });
    if($scope.all || checked > 0){
        alert("Selected coupons!");
    }
    else if(checked === 0){
        alert("Select at least one coupon");
    }
}
```

Then, my code for the API:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});

const dbConfig = {
    user: "daUser",
    password: "daPass",
    server: "daServa",
    database: "daDB"
};

const executeQuery = function (res, query, parameters) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`There's an error: ${err}`);
            res.send(err);
            sql.close();
        }
        else {
            var request = new sql.Request();

            if (parameters && parameters.length > 0) {
                parameters.forEach(function (p) {
                    request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
                });
            }


            request.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`Theres an error: ${err}`);
                    res.send(err);
                    sql.close();
                }
                else {
                    res.send(result);
                    sql.close();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

app.post("/api/testApi", function(req, res){
    parameters = [
        { name: 'CouponId', sqltype: sql.VarChar, value: req.body.CouponId }
    ];

    var query = "INSERT INTO [Table_A] VALUES(@CouponId)";
    executeQuery(res, query, parameters);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

This is the code that usually works for an object. My question is: how can i send `result` (where result is the obtained array) on the API. I need to change something on my code on `parameters`?

Hope you can help me. I'm using Javascript, Node, Express and SQL Server.

Comment: What do you mean "how can i save result on the API" ?

Comment: Plus - "how can i save result on the API" and "How to post an array to Express API" sound like completely different questions. Can you please clarify the question and title?

Comment: Well `result` is the array... you're right, it's confusing. I edited the question

Comment: If you can have code samples of what you want to see or a user-story that would be great. the phrasing "how can I save X on the api" is still confusing. You don't save anything on an API.

Answer (score 0):

## How to post an array to Express API

In angular you simply do `$http.post(url, data)`.

If you assign data to an object that has an array, it will reach express.
Then express can parse the body since you have `app.use(express.bodyParser());` so the object should be available to you on the body.

### URL Query Params

If you are trying to use query parameters, to pass an array, lets say on attribute `items` so you simply declare it multiple times

`items=1&items=2&items=3` should be parsed to `req.query.items === [1,2,3]`